# cant jquery.last() not Supported by ie 

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

this is my code :

```
$('script').last().parent().html('kkkk')
```

but it show error in ie ,

so what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: It's likely more to do with the `$('script')` part. What are you actually trying to achieve with this piece of code, as more than likely when it runs the Javascript inside that script tag has already been run.

Comment: It would be nice if you specified what you are trying to accomplish and what the error is that you are seeing in ie.

Comment: the error is :  Object does not support this property or method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$('script:last').last().parent().html('kkkk')`

That seams to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your script's parent... but this works

http://jsfiddle.net/hkrAx/

Assumming you are targeting the wrapper of a `<script />` tag.